# Why this code doesn't allow me to receive the whole array?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string bin(int n){
    string x=""; 
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int z=n%2; 
        x+=to_string(z); 
        n%=2;
    }  
    return x;
}

int main(){
    int t; 
    cin>>t; 
    while(t--)
    {
        int n; 
        cin>>n; 
        int a[n]; 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {    
            cin>>a[i]; 
            string x=bin(a[i]); 
            int u=x.size();
            int cnt=0;        
            for(int g=0;g<u;g++)
            {
                if(x[g]=='1') 
                    ++cnt; 
            }
            cout<<cnt<<' ';
       }
        cout<<'\n';
   }
}
```

This code is given several test cases and each test case will have an array of `n` integers, for each element in the array I should count the number of ones in the binary representation of it. I wrote a function that expects an integer and returns a string containing the binary representation of it. But I wonder why my code does not end, and not allowing me to receive other numbers in array.

For instance, there's one test case and and only array of `2` integers if I inputted 1 and wait for ever to enter the second number, what's happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Does anybody know why there's such a huge influx of questions on this site that use #include <bits/stdc++.h>? Do I have confirmation bias, or is it really a recent thing?

Comment: I hate to say it but there are a lot of bad programming techniques in your code.  Some of them are even illegal in standard C++. I suggest getting a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and see how they write code in there.

Comment: @John almost any **tutorial** online will have it, as well as any competitive programming challenges.

Comment: @John `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a widely used shortcut popular in the programming challenge world as it saves typing.  It's also the start of the school year and some bad books use it so you see an uptick in it's use in questions.

Comment: what is the input? (if you dont know because the tests are confidential, then write your own test)

Comment: I believe you meant `n/=2;` instead of `n %= 2;`, if `n` at some point is odd, the  while loop inside bin function will run forever.

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` saves time typing, but it makes build times close to an order of magnitude slower. Build the code two-three times and you've eaten up the time savings (or you type too slowly to stand a chance).

Comment: That header also makes it a pain-in-the-neck to have to remove and replace with the proper headers if the compiler is Visual Studio.  Can you imagine a programmer applying for a job, only learned from those "competitive websites", and not know the first line of code if they were given Visual Studio as the compiler?

Comment: You can use `x += ('0' + (n & 1));` instead of calling `tostring`.  Your binary digit characters will be `'0'` or `'1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `bin` function reduced to the bare minimum:

```
string bin(int n){
    while(n!=0)
    {
        n%=2;
    }  
    return {};
}
```

If `n` is even you will set it to `0` on the first iteration, otherwise you set it to `1` and never change it afterwards (`1%2==1`). Hence you have a endless loop. I won't spoil you the "fun" of completing the exercise, so I will just point you to using a debugger. If you step trough your code line by line you could have observed how `n` never changes and why the loop wont stop.

PS: (spoiler-alert) you might want to take a look at `std::bitset` (end of spoiler)